# I am having issues with getting Pong paddle to move up and down

Tags: python, self, pong

I am reading through Python Crash Course and have come to an issue. I am building my game using modified code from the book. When I was adding limitations to how far the paddle can go on the screen which is edge to edge hopefully I added this code:

```
if self.moving_up and self.rect.top < self.screen_rect.top:
```

and

```
if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom > 0:
```

It freezes my paddle and will not change the location of the paddle. I need to learn what is freezing my paddle.

```
import pygame
```

class Paddle:

```
def __init__(self, pg_game):
    self.screen = pg_game.screen
    self.settings = pg_game.settings
    self.screen_rect = pg_game.screen.get_rect()
    
    self.image = pygame.image.load('images/PongAssets.bmp')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    
    self.rect.midright = self.screen_rect.midright
    
    self.y = float(self.rect.y)
    
    self.moving_up = False
    self.moving_down = False
        

def update(self):
    if self.moving_up and self.rect.top < self.screen_rect.top:
        self.y -= self.settings.paddle_speed
    if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom > 0:
        self.y += self.settings.paddle_speed
        
    
    self.rect.y = self.y
        
           
def blitme(self):
    
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Comment: `self.screen_rect.top` will always be 0 so your paddle can only move it it's intersecting the top of the screen

Comment: Do you have a solution you would use to get it working?

Comment: The top of the screen has a y-value of zero. So in your `moving_up` block, you want to allow movement if the y-value (or `self.rect.top`) is greater than zero.